# Mantaflow. The liquid just doesn't respect the collision object

Tags: fluid-simulation

Mantaflow. The liquid just doesn't want to properly respect the collision object. I've watched countless tutorials and still can't get it right.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

[Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-HYhDr6gj_xkY77f7PcLSfR4Yw_jOhI3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please use the [built in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)
to add images to your posts. Use any image editor or online optimizer 
if you must resize an image.
Information should be immediately visible to those who would answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this seems to be some bug and have seen several posts.   One suggested [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174833/111042) was to use a Surface Thickness equal to the volume of the collision object.   However, Thickness is defined in the docs as an ADDITIONAL dimension beyond the mesh.  When I play with Thickness, it works but has to be a minimum of 0.5 and has a deleterious effect on the liquid boundaries as you'll see here:
[image: use of Surface Thickness in a liquid collision mesh]

I dread to suggestion a solution where a duplicate, hidden collision object that is some 0.5 (what is the translation to units?!!) larger than the visible collision object.

Perhaps another (degenerate) solution is to set "Is Planer" if the collision object is simple or if you break up the collision object into sub-objects. This appears to work.

[image]

So until others can be helpful in assisting with a solution (or admission of a bug), then perhaps there is something useful here.