# The liquid inside the bottle is looking smaller than the real size

Tags: rendering, lighting, glass

[image]

The issue is that the liquid is appearing small in the glass and leaving a large space but in reality it is bigger than that. I thought is was the light so I added different HDRI and it still gives the same result.

I did research on the IOR of glass and Whiskey and it still gave me this.

What are some things you feel I can do to make the liquid appear evenly through out the glass?

Comment: Check the bottle and liquid object normals.

Comment: I think the trick here was to have the liquid object intersect the bottle object to get the desired result. Otherwise you'd have to use unrealistic IOR.

Comment: If this is a Liquid domain simulation, you'll want to check the glass object that is has a fluid Effector Collision type modifier.  Unfortunately with blender, it needs to have a Surface Thickness of at least 0.5 to actually work.  This will leave the interior liquid constrained as you noticed.   The [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209934/111042) is to remove this Effector, duplicate the bottle (invisible/unrendered), scale it upwards, and add the 0.5 thick collision effector.  You'll have to play around with scale, as 0.5 is related to ... *what*!

Comment: @james_t: Love your practical hints...and that's the way - i think - it works. Fake it. Stop trying to do it "realistic" because we are just pixel pusher ;)

Comment: @Chris -- as an engineering professor once told our class: 2-digit accuracy is good enough for government work!